# Allocate an array with garbage (heap garbage values)

Tags: java-9, unsafe

I got this question on an interview and even if it may sound stupid, I found it interesting. So, the question is, how would you initialize an array with heap garbage (something that is not `zeroes` only).

For example as opposed to:

```
int [] ints = new int[10];
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
```

The last print will guarantee that everything is `zeroes` only.

But is there such a way that you could instantiate this array with potential values that are *not* zeroes?

Comment: Is this specific to Java9? Also, IMHO the question isn't really clear in terms of *last print will guarantee that everything is zeroes only* or did you try answering your question there?

Comment: @nullpointer yes this is specific to 9, as this method was added in 9 IIRC. Unfortunately I don't remember the exact way this was asked, but it was better than I have it here

Comment: @nullpointer also I don't get your point here... by default all primitive arrays are initialized with their default values, for int this is zero

Comment: Ohk, did you mean [`Arrays.toString(ints)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-) is added in Java9? Ah, i get it from Alan's comment.. you mean the method in unsafe is added in Java9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, there are two things.

I don't know the exact point of this question, as it requires some investigation of the `Unsafe` class that is not done on a daily basis. May be the company (which I failed the interview anyway), *really* does this low level programming.

And second, I got very lucky, I only found out about this while looking how String concat is done, where I first saw this and was intrigued by it.

```
    jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe unsafe = getUnsafe();

    for (;;) {
        int[] arr = (int[]) unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int.class, 10);
        int sum = Arrays.stream(arr).sum();
        if (sum != 0) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
            break;
        }
    }
```

This is documented as:

> Allocates an array of a given type, but does not do zeroing.

Comment: jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe != sun.misc.Unsafe. Best to stay well away from jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe as it's JDK internal and likely to be refactored or changed at any time.

Comment: @AlanBateman fully agreed, as I said I dont know the point of the question to begin with

Comment: Interesting.  Does `sun.misc.Unsafe` offer a similar method?  And I can't imagine why a company would ask a question like this; low-level programming in Java sounds very uncommon, especially for an interview question.

Comment: I can't imagine the interviewer knowing this method in the JDK internal Unsafe. Maybe it was a trick question?

Comment: @AlanBateman apparently he did, I also got a few other questions from `Unsafe` related to release/acquire semantics... It was the toughest interview I have ever had (which I miserably failed I think)

Comment: @Eugene it seems to be a common pattern that interviewers apparently just want to show off with their irrelevant knowledge instead of finding a good programmer for the job.

Comment: @Holger I hope so, I got a little emotionally distorted by it, there were 51 questions that I only answered 11 of them. anyhow, I've moved on I guess